# Using SLF4J in Akka

Tags: java, logging, akka, slf4j

I followed [Logging Doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/logging.html) for using `SLF4J` with `logback` in my Akka application. But i have problem in logging in non-actor classes: I can not log MDCs (e.g. `sourceActorSystem`) in my non-actor classes by a SLF4J logger. Here is my simple application:

1- `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2- `application.conf`:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

3- `logback.xml` which uses `sourceThread`, `akkaSource`, and `sourceActorSystem` MDCs:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" > 
    <contextName>akka-sample</contextName>
    <jmxConfigurator />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%contextName] [%X{sourceThread}] [%X{sourceActorSystem}] [%X{akkaSource}] %logger{40} -| %msg %rEx%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

4- `UserActor`: An actor class which logs by `DiagnosticLoggingAdapter`:

```
public class UserActor extends AbstractActor {
    DiagnosticLoggingAdapter logger = Logging.getLogger(this);
    Handler handler = new Handler(); // non-actor class

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(UserActor.class, UserActor::new);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(UserMessages.Register.class, register -> {
                logger.info("{} received", register);
                // Delegate message-handling to a non-actor class
                handler.onRegister(register, getSelf(), getSender());
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

5- `Handler`: A non-actor class which logs by `SLF4J` logger. Each `UserActor` instance has a `Handler` field for delegating message-handling to it:

```
public class Handler {
    org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public void onRegister(UserMessages.Register register, ActorRef self, ActorRef sender) {
        logger.info("Handling {}", register);
        sender.tell(new UserMessages.Registered(), self);
    }
}
```

6- Simple application:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ActorSystem system = null;
        try {
            system = ActorSystem.create("akka-system");
            ActorRef user1 = system.actorOf(UserActor.props(), "user-1");
            ActorRef user2 = system.actorOf(UserActor.props(), "user-2");
            user2.tell(UserMessages.Register.builder().userId("1").build(), user1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } finally {
            system.terminate();
        }
    }
}
```

Log Output:

```
18:07:30 INFO  [akka-sample] [] [] [] akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger -| Slf4jLogger started 
18:07:30 INFO  [akka-sample] [akka-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka-system] [akka://akka-system/user/user-2] x.y.akka.UserActor -| UserMessages.Register(userId=1) received 
18:07:30 INFO  [akka-sample] [] [] [] x.y.akka.Handler -| Handling UserMessages.Register(userId=1)
```

As you can see, only log in `UserActor` (actor class) has `sourceThread`, `akkaSource`, and `sourceActorSystem` MDCs; But in `Handler` (non-actor) they are empty. Also if i change `akka.event.DiagnosticLoggingAdapter` in `UserActor` to `org.slf4j.Logger`, these MDCs become empty.

Comment: What's the problem? They are empty because they do not come from inside an actor system. So this is correct behaviour, don't you think?

Comment: @RobinGreen Why MDCs are not passed to SLF4J logger? `Handler#onRegister` is only called when a `Register` message received by an `UserActor`, so `handler` and actor have same thread.